# Unable to load class declared as < mapping class="Package.Class" /> in the configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports, ireport, hibernate-mapping

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
        <hibernate-configuration>
          <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
              <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/UsoSurvey</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">UsoSurvey</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">UsoSurvey</property>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>   
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

             <!-- configuration pool via c3p0-->  
           <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>  
           <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property> <!-- seconds -->  
           <property name="c3p0.max_size">10</property>  
           <property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property>  
           <property name="c3p0.min_size">1</property>  
           <property name="c3p0.timeout">100</property> <!-- seconds -->

            <mapping class="Modelo.Grpusuario"/>
            <mapping class="Modelo.Menu"/>
            <mapping class="Modelo.Encuesta"/>
...
```

**In iReport**
Tools->Options->iReport->Classpath

C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UsoSurvey\src\java\Util   -> I*n this folder is the mapping class*

C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UsoSurvey\src\java\Modelo -> *In this folder are the model classes*

**Grpusuario.java**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrador
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "grpusuarios", catalog = "UsoSurvey", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Grpusuario.findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM Grpusuario g"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Grpusuario.findByGrupo", query = "SELECT g FROM Grpusuario g WHERE g.grupo = :grupo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Grpusuario.findByDescripcion", query = "SELECT g FROM Grpusuario g WHERE g.descripcion = :descripcion")})
public class Grpusuario implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "grupo")
    private Integer grupo;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 64)
    @Column(name = "descripcion")
    private String descripcion;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "secLevel")
    private Collection<Menu> menuCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "grupo", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<Usuario> usuarioCollection;

    public Grpusuario() {
    }
....
```

but when trying to create the connection I get the following error: **unable to load class declared as `< mapping class="Modelo.Grpusuario" />` in the configuration**

Comment: Please show the mapping class

Comment: The mapping class is this `<mapping class="Modelo.Grpusuario"/>`